# Get value from firebase and use it in useState React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

First the user chooses his allergies by clicking on a toggle button. If the state is true or false the **state** is being added successfully to firebase.

[Allergy Selctor Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxlEh.png)

Then in my homepage I want to retrieve that allergy state and apply it in the allergy list state located on home page.
[Home Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muNsK.png)

I am able to get the state value from firebase using this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("userDb")
      .where("userId", "==", user.email)
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          const newTypes = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const type = doc.data();
            newTypes.push(type);
          });

          setTypes(newTypes[0].Dairy);
setStatus(type);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFav = async () => {
      try {
        const list = [];
        await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("userDb")
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const { Dairy, Peanut } = doc.data();
              list.push({
                userid: doc.id,
                dairy: Dairy,
                peanut: Peanut,
              });
            });
          });
        setPosts(list);
        if (loading) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchFav();

    searchApi(term);
  }, []);
```

But I don't know how to apply this to my state. I wanted to use type in status(type) which gets the actual true/false value when I console log it gets the right value from firebase but for some reason its always true in status(type);

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState(type);

          <Button
          onPress={() => setStatus(!status)}
          title={`Prevent Dairy: ${
            status ? "on (search again for new results)" : "off"
          }`}
          ></Button>
```

I want it to be dynamic as the user can change his allergies so I didn't use route.params for the allergies.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what's `type`? in your first code, `type` seems to be an `Object`, but on the last codes you treat it as a `boolean`.

Comment: yes it is an Object, since the value is false I presumed it would work.

Comment: I think the problem is, in useEffect() you set status `setStatus(type)` on mounting and it will set the status to an Object. When it render the status will have the value of that Object hence it will always be true.

Comment: I tried using typeof and it is a string both the times, I still don't know why the state isn't working. do you have any other approach if you were using buttons to toggle state?